# SQL link 5 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Much more to it but there are 3 tables...

```
employees  
employee_id  

licenses  
license_id  
employee_id  


companies  
company_id  
employee_id  

SELECT  * FROM employees  
LEFT JOIN licenses  
ON employees.employee_id = licenses.employee_id   
LEFT JOIN companies  
ON employees.employee_id = companies.employee_id  
GROUP BY employees.employee_id
```

I can only get it so either licenses OR companies returns a value and the other returns NULL.  How can I get it so BOTH tables return values?  Seems so easy but it isn't working in this case and I can't figure out why...

EDIT:  Here is some more info.
Not every employee has a license.
Not every employee has a company.

Would like to return `employee_id  license_id (if exists, else NULL)  company_id (if exists, else NULL)`

Take the case where an employee has both a license_id and a company_id.  By removing one of the JOIN clauses, can return the corresponding value.  However, when both are combined, only return the company_id and license_id returns NULL.

Weird, right?  Any ideas or is more info needed?

DATA:
employee_id
1
2
3

employee_id  license_id
1     1
2    1
3   2

employee_id  company_id 
1  1
2  1
3  2

SORRY FOR WASTING TIME

The table schema is screwed up and redundant.  This was an inherited schema and I was just considering the SQL, not the underlying structure.  Database needs restructuring.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.   Show some sample data for all three tables, and then show what you expect the query to return and what you actually get.

Comment: `GROUP BY employee_id` is ambiguous. Use `GROUP BY employees.employee_id`.

Comment: @karolis correct, just forgot the employees table designation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are alot of different `JOIN` types. My suggestion would be to do some reading about them to figure it out. You can use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT  * 
FROM employees  
FULL OUTER JOIN licenses  
    ON employees.employee_id = licenses.employee_id   
FULL OUTER JOIN companies  
    ON employees.employee_id = companies.employee_id  
GROUP BY employee_id
```

It is difficult to figure exactly what you want without seeing any data. But here is a handy visual explanation of SQL Joins.  I keep it bookmarked for those times that I need some help.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Same comment.  Ha.   
Great link. Visual representation of Venn's is great. I believe a LEFT JOIN is the correct join for my case but can't return the results as I desired

Comment: It would be a big help if you posted some data.

Comment: Data shared.  If more details or result sets would help, just let me know.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for help.  Realized the database structure is messed up.  Needs normalization before SQL should be attempted.

Comment: yeah DB design is critical before you start writing SQL

Answer (score 1):

This is very difficult to answer without seeing the data in the tables. So I'll make the assumption, that there are rows in each table that all have a single Employee_ID that is the same, so the joins work. While your testing this I would suggest picking one Employee_id to work with too, just to simplify the output while you test.

Based on my assumptions, I switched your queries to inner joins, this will only show rows that match on the Employee_id. I also used "aliasing". The single letter I put after each table pointer saves a lot of typing.

```
SELECT *
FROM  employees e
INNER JOIN licenses l
    ON e.employee_id = l.employee_id
INNER JOIN companies 
    ON e.employee_id = c.employee_id
GROUP BY   employee_id
```

If you're new to SQL joins, [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) may be helpful too. Best of luck!

Comment: Each INNER JOIN by itself returns the proper rows.  When combined as you show above, returns empty set.  Any thoughts?  Great comment on aliasing too.  The tables are aliased in the code but weren't in the example.

Comment: Yep, this means that one of your tables doesn't have the right Employee_id. I'd check the employee_id data type and make sure they are all integers, then I would add a "Where employee_id = (some number) at the end of my query, where some number was something you absolutely new was in all three tables.  If the datatypes are the same and the number is in each table, it will resolve a row.

Answer (score 0):

This is my favorite article on the subject.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins.aspx

Try

```
FULL OUTER JOIN
```

Comment: Great link.  Visual representation of Venn's is great.  I believe a LEFT JOIN is the correct join for my case but can't return the results as I desired.